# How to go to previous tab by click on a button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I am using bootstrap form-wizard to register data in the database in multi steps, the problem is here that I am a  beginner in js and don't know a lot.
I have some codes below, there is a `next` button that when I click on it go to the next tab. I want to add a button that when I click on it to go to the previous tab and I don't know to code it, please help me.
thanks in advance.!

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="stepwizard">
     <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
     <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
        <p>Step 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
        <p>Step 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<form role="form">
<div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3> Step 1</h3>
            //here go to the next tab
            <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3> Step3</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Finish!</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Previous</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js code:-**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
        allWells = $('.setup-content'),
        allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

allWells.hide();

navListItems.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $item = $(this);

    if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
        navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
        $item.addClass('btn-primary');
        allWells.hide();
        $target.show();
        $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
    }
});
// go to the next tab when clicked on nextBtn
allNextBtn.click(function(){
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
        curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
        nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
        curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
        isValid = true;

    $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
        if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
            isValid = false;
            $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
        }
    }

    if (isValid)
        nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
});

$('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this..

add "Previous Button" and when click previous button we select previous element.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
                    allWells = $('.setup-content'),
                    allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');
                    allPrevBtn = $('.prevBtn');

            allWells.hide();

            navListItems.click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
                        $item = $(this);

                if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
                    navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
                    $item.addClass('btn-primary');
                    allWells.hide();
                    $target.show();
                    $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
                }
            });
            // go to the next tab when clicked on nextBtn
            allNextBtn.click(function(){
                var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
                    curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
                    nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
                    curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
                    isValid = true;

                $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
                for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
                    if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
                        isValid = false;
                        $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
                    }
                }

                if (isValid)
                    nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
            });

            allPrevBtn.click(function(){
                var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
                    curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
                    nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().prev().children("a"),
                    curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
                    isValid = true;

                $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
                for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
                    if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
                        isValid = false;
                        $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
                    }
                }

                if (isValid)
                    nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
            });

            $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
        });
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="stepwizard">
          <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
            <div class="stepwizard-step">
              <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
              <p>Step 1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="stepwizard-step">
              <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
              <p>Step 2</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <form role="form">
      <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3> Step 1</h3>
                  //here go to the next tab
                  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
                  
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3> Step3</h3>
                  <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Finish!</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Previous</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```